# Can't access nested object properties with TWIG

Tags: php, symfony, nested, twig

**Tl;DR** Twig won't let me drill down into a nested object.

I have this collection of json_decoded objects that has a nested object within it. When trying to output a property of the nested object I get an error like:

> Item "text" for "" does not exist

when I try a to dump out the nested object i can see it fine... but I can't access any of it's properties. Here's the dump of the "entire" parent object

```
Using this in my loop
{% for item in allFields %}

    {{ dump(item) }}

{% endfor %}
```

[image: Full Dump]

And here is the dump of the nested label object its self using {{dump(item.label)}} in my loop

```
Using this in my loop
{% for item in allFields %}

    {{ dump(item.label) }}

{% endfor %}
```

[image: Label Dump]

I'm attempting to get the text property (and others) of the label class by using a twig for loop like so:

```
{% for item in allFields %}

    {{ item.label.text }}

{% endfor %}
```

And it is here that I get the error

> Item "text" for "" does not exist

Comment: Maybe not all of your item's label got a text field?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is weird. One though: this happened to me on one occasion when my `EntityManager` was running out of memory due to very complex hydration query. I'm thinking that some part of data gets lots here and you get this error.

So, how many item do you have in this `allFields` list?

In order to troubleshoot this I suggest you do:

```
{% for item in allFields %}

    {{ item.label is null or item.label == "" ? "***EMPTY-LABEL***" : item.label.text }}

{% endfor %}
```

Comment: This did it... Thank you so much. The collection in fairly large numbering in the 100's. And there were 4 that were not populated with label objects. So it wasn't a twig problem PEBKAC all the way :P